# PHP Array extract or pull everything from the API JSON for html output

Tags: php, json, api, foreach, associative-array

I'm using PHP and I have this JSON data which I already decoded into my HTML using file_get_content and the json_decode and then (

```
?>
    <pre>
       <?php
           print_r($animeList);
        ?>
    </pre>
 <?php
```

) just to see what I'm dealing with but now I need to format it **nicely** into my webpage but it doesn't work. Its giving me some date and no spaces between different sets. How to output data now from this Array using foreach loop?

This is what i've tried (**inside index.php**) but its giving me wrong output:

```
if ($_GET['fields'] =='films'): 
            ?>
            <ol>
                <?php foreach ( $animeList as $films ) : ?>
                    <?php
                        foreach ($films as $url) : ?>
                        
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $url; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach;  ?>
                <?php endforeach;  ?>
            </ol>
            <?php endif; ?> 
        <?php
```

This what I have inside $**animeList** (this is for debugging inside webpage)

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe
                [title] => Castle in the Sky
                [description] => The orphan Sheeta inherited a mysterious crystal that links her to the mythical sky-kingdom of Laputa. With the help of resourceful Pazu and a rollicking band of sky pirates, she makes her way to the ruins of the once-great civilization. Sheeta and Pazu must outwit the evil Muska, who plans to use Laputa's science to make himself ruler of the world.
                [director] => Hayao Miyazaki
                [producer] => Isao Takahata
                [release_date] => 1986
                [rt_score] => 95
                [people] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/
                    )
            )
    
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12cfb892-aac0-4c5b-94af-521852e46d6a
            [title] => Grave of the Fireflies
            [description] => In the latter part of World War II, a boy and his sister, orphaned when their mother is killed in the firebombing of Tokyo, are left to survive on their own in what remains of civilian life in Japan. The plot follows this boy and his sister as they do their best to survive in the Japanese countryside, battling hunger, prejudice, and pride in their own quiet, personal battle.
            [director] => Isao Takahata
            [producer] => Toru Hara
            [release_date] => 1988
            [rt_score] => 97
            [people] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/
                )
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 58611129-2dbc-4a81-a72f-77ddfc1b1b49
            [title] => My Neighbor Totoro
            [description] => Two sisters move to the country with their father in order to be closer to their hospitalized mother, and discover the surrounding trees are inhabited by Totoros, magical spirits of the forest. When the youngest runs away from home, the older sister seeks help from the spirits to find her.
            [director] => Hayao Miyazaki
            [producer] => Hayao Miyazaki
            [release_date] => 1988
            [rt_score] => 93
            [people] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/986faac6-67e3-4fb8-a9ee-bad077c2e7fe
                    [1] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/d5df3c04-f355-4038-833c-83bd3502b6b9
                    [2] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/3031caa8-eb1a-41c6-ab93-dd091b541e11
                    [3] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/87b68b97-3774-495b-bf80-495a5f3e672d
                    [4] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/d39deecb-2bd0-4770-8b45-485f26e1381f
                    [5] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/591524bc-04fe-4e60-8d61-2425e42ffb2a
                    [6] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/c491755a-407d-4d6e-b58a-240ec78b5061
                    [7] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/f467e18e-3694-409f-bdb3-be891ade1106
                    [8] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/08ffbce4-7f94-476a-95bc-76d3c3969c19
                    [9] => https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people/0f8ef701-b4c7-4f15-bd15-368c7fe38d0a
                )
        )
)
```

So i'm seeing this output, as you can see there no spaces between 3 different sets of data and 'people' Arrays did not output.

[image]

Comment: You probably should test if `$url` is an array. And print it as a different way if it's true. ([`is_array()`](https://php.net/is_array)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested lists to display your data.

```
<ol>
    <?php foreach ( $animeList as $films ) : ?>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($films as $url) : ?>
                <li><?php 
                    if (! is_array($url)) {
                        echo $url; 
                    }
                ?></li>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
</ol>
```

For the key "people", you need to do another loop.

*EDIT* with the "sub-list" :

```
<ol>
    <?php foreach ( $animeList as $films ) : ?>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($films as $key => $url) : ?>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $key ?>

                    <?php 
                    if (! is_array($url)) {
                        echo $url; 
                    }
                    else {
                    ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($url as $value) : ?>
                                <li><?php echo $value ?></li>
                            <?php endforeach;  ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php
                    }

                ?></li>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach;  ?>
</ol>
```

Here is how corrected output looks now:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir! That solves half of my problem, really appreciated. I'll try another loop later and will post a reply if it worked.

Comment: @AlecTech I've added a new version with "sub list" displayed.

Comment: I just tested it. Now its working as expected, thank you once again!

Comment: @AlecTech You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as closed :) thank you.